# Why this trim doesn't work the way it's supposed to be?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim trimstr = "[]".ToCharArray
somestring= somestring.Trim(trimstr)
```

It changes `"[Hello]"` into `"Hello]"`

I think it should have been `"Hello"`

Comment: No [it doesn't](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s3Hgwc)

Comment: I can’t reproduce that. https://ideone.com/HnVlKB Are you sure your string doesn’t have trailing whitespace or something?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake.

The original text is `"[Hello] "` with a space after it. It seems that

`"[Hello]".Trim("[]".ToCharArray)` will indeed becomes `"Hello"`

However

`"[Hello]".Trim("[]".ToCharArray)` will indeed becomes `"Hello] "`

Comment: whats the difference in those two??? [pasted from the second](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AzQyAv)  If the second was supposed to be like this here: `"[Hello] "`, trim is still working like it should (there is no trailing ']')

Answer (score 0):

If you want **spaces** to be trimmed, then **add a space** to your character array:

```
Debug.Print("[Hello] ".Trim("[] ".ToCharArray))
```